# How to patch a slipper?

Tags: home, comfort, shoes, repair

Is there a good way to patch up this slipper? Whenever I try to slip it on, my toes or sock will get stuck in those holes. I thought about using a packaging tape, but that’s just going to make it worse. I feel like there’s still useful life left in this pair of slippers. How should I patch it up?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What about just cutting a piece of fabric to cover the entire piece to the left of the velcro and sewing it in place? Fabric would stay in place and not roll at the edges like tape may.

Answer (score 1):

If they were mine, I'd use [gaffer tape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaffer_tape).  Stick it over the whole area and trim to size but be sure to leave enough to turn it onto the top surface so that you don't catch a raw tape edge when you put on the slipper